# ViewPager - determine when page is going out of view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm using ViewPager in my app to display information for a range of dates - with each page containing information for corresponding date.  There's quite a bit of this information, along with user interaction to change this info.  When the information changes, I need to save it to sqlite database.

While I can automatically save the information to DB every time it's changed by user interaction, this is extremely inefficient - and I want to save it once.  When a page is going out of view, it may be recycled thereby loosing the information.  Ideally, I want to save the info for a date into the database when the page is going out of view - but I can't find a way to hook to that event.

It's very easy to see when the new page is being presented, using `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`, however I can't see a way of catching the page going out of view - methods are either geared toward catching the new page going into view or generic scroll, which may or may not indicate the page going out.

I am already extending from `FragmentStatePageAdapter` for my adapter, so could possibly hook into something there.  Unfortunately, Android documentation is notoriously sparse for anything beyond common scenarios - and reading the [`FragmentStatePageAdapter` API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) provides very little information beyond giving me an idea that this is probably the right way forward - possibly with `saveState` and `restoreState` methods - but those seem to be dealing with the state of the adapter, rather than fragments for each page.

Can anyone suggest a way to solve this?

Comment: "When a page is going out of view, it may be recycled thereby loosing the information" -- what do you mean by "going out of view"? `ViewPager` itself keeps at least 3 pages around, and optionally more.

Comment: By out of view I mean literally when it is going to not be visible to the user any more - when another page is about to become visible.

Comment: For a typical `ViewPager`, with only one visible page, I don't see the difference between detecting when a new page comes into view (`OnPageChangeListener`) and when the old page goes out of view.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, but how can I determine what page just went out of view? I know the index of newly visible page, but not the one that was just replaced

Comment: "how can I determine what page just went out of view?" -- keep track of the last-viewed page in an `int`, that you update in your `OnPageChangeListener`.